# Django project - database table in cache

Tags: python, django, performance, memory, redis

I have a Django(python) project running on a digitalocean.com droplet. Because the configurations options are limited I have an excess of free memory. I'm thinking about using that available memory, and load some database tables in memory. I already have a Redis server caching some views. Is it possible to cache a database whole table? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no point (if you want to be able to query those tables with models or SQL).

Either your RDBMS (MySQL, Postgres, ...) will deal with caching tables in memory, or alternately the Linux file page cache will deal with keeping the underlying data files properly in memory.

Comment: Ok, so the RDBMS (postgres in my case) has its own caching system. Thanks